# ffmpeg fails when executing example command to convert using VP8

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, webm, scoop

I am following the tutorial [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8), and executing the first example command yeilds an error.

The ffmpeg version I have has libvpx and libvorbis enabled.

When I run this command: `ffmpeg -i aaa.mp4 -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm`, I get:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'aaa.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-11-19T16:35:35.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:37.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18672 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 18375 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-19T16:35:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-11-19T16:35:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
[NULL @ 0000018b84220500] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libvpx'
libvpx: Invalid argument
```

**Edit:**

The version of ffmpeg I have is installed using scoop package manager, and it seems to be the issue.

Comment: Command looks valid. I am unable to get the same error with FFmpeg 4.3. Check that the command you provided is the same that you executed and make sure there are no non-standard characters in the command.

Comment: @llogan Thanks. It seems it is because of scoop package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg installed via scoop seems to be culprit. A work around is to either to run the command in cmd or to use `ffmpeg.exe` in PowerShell, like:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i aaa.mp4 -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/issues/2018